# How to update Elasticsearch data from mysql?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I havee 3 tables on mysql.

And indexed the data to elasticsearch.

It worked with below.(logstash config)

```
input {

                 jdbc {
                jdbc_driver_library => "lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar"
                jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
                jdbc_user => "test"
                jdbc_password => "test"
                statement => "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
                schedule => "* * * * *"
                                        type => "table1"


                 }
    //  
    // two more inputs
    //

}

output {
                stdout {codec => rubydebug}
                if [type] == "table1" {
                        elasticsearch {
                                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                                                 index => "test"
                                                document_type => "%{type}"
                                                document_id => "%{id}"
                                                template => "./template"
                                                template_overwrite => true
                                 }
                }
             //
             // two more outputs
             //

}
```

I deleted other two inputs and outputs, some rows from TABLE1 on mysql.

And started logstash.

It was not updated.

So, typed

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*'
```

and restared logstash again.

But three tables were added again with same rows on elasticsearch.

How to update elasticsearch data automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're missing out [use column value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-use_column_value), [tracking column](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-tracking_column) and it's type in your `jdbc` input:

```
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    jdbc_user => "test"
    jdbc_password => "test"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    type => "table1"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"  <-- this should be the incrementing value in your table
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"    
}
```

*tracking_column* is used in order to trace which column to map when updating values in your table. This should do the trick for you. Hope it helps!

Comment: Omg. I am using logstash version 2.1.1 and it doesn't support use_column_value, tracking_column, tracking_column_type. Is there other way to solve this problem on version 2.1.1?

Comment: I have updated 2.1.1 to 2.4.1. And Added three line of code.               use_column_value => true
                tracking_column => "id"
                lowercase_column_names => false.
it returned same value

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would work without **tracking_column_type => "numeric"**, since I've tried with that only.  I'll get back to you after checking if there's any workaround for this.

Comment: I deleted a row and ran curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*' again and ran logstash again. then the row was deleted. But garbage rows were still remain(I deleted tables and rows last month). Also it wasn't automatically updated. Should I reinstall elasticsearch?

Comment: Well if you're to make the changes from the place where you left off, (like having the last updated id) then yes you may have to delete the indice since the changes will be applied on the new rows, but if you're still reading it from the first row itself then you don't have to. Reinstall in the sense? You mean to restart the service?

Comment: No, reinstall. I deleted some folders which is node name in elasticsearch/data. But previous data was appeared again.
e.g) 1 2 3 4 5 rows were in the table. and I removed all.(or remove table)
added rows 1 2 3 to table
1 2 3 were new and 4 5 were previous.

Comment: And is it necessary to use curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200*' when I delete a record? even logstash is running?

Comment: You could only delete that particular record by it's id, by using [Delete API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-delete.html#docs-delete)